# I am unable to connect to any (Oracle) DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I was unable to connect to my DB that I had created long ago.
So I decided to create a new one.

[image: o]

Oracle Home:

`ORACLE_HOME`: D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1

I had added a path as `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin`

tnsnames.ora was set as TNS_ADMIN

**tnsnames.ora**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-OCHT3VN)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

How can I overcome this error?

It's probably something related to connecting with the DB.

Please let me know if more info is needed.

When I try to connect to oracle to my old db...This comes (`sqlplus` + `scott/tiger`)

```
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

Comment: can you share your TNS_ADMIN en-var ? this en-var *should* contain path to the `tnsnames.ora`. And *should not* have `tnsnames.ora` at the end of it

Comment: Oh..Let me change it and update you asap

Comment: i.e. it should be set to `D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin` based on the file you showed.

Comment: Does this value for TNS_ADMIN seem right `D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\ADMIN`?

Comment: While going through the `dbca` setup, I just went with the default options (except name and pass) ... I hope that isn't causing any error

Comment: That error still comes..

Comment: I don't really have any important data there...is there any way to reinstall everything?

Comment: `Cannot connect to shared memory realm` seems to indicate the database isn't started. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/startup.htm

Comment: You can try using the full connection string instead of TNS.  For example: ```SERVERNAME:1521/INSTANCENAME```

Comment: I just get connected to a idle instance,

Comment: This is what the `startup` command yields `ORA-02778: Name given for the log directory is invalid`